# Retrofit Can't return Data error code 400

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm probably doing something wrong, I'm trying to login in API and no data return and it returns error code 400 
what am I doing wrong?

This my API Detail: [Image from postman take look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK4Cp.png)

My Retrofit API Code:

```
private static Retrofit retrofit;
private static Retrofit.Builder builder;
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://tajmeelapi.red-uae.com/Tajmeel/Api/";

public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    }
    return retrofit =builder.build();
}
```

my login method :

```
 @POST("token")
 Call<TokenResponse> loginUser(@Body Login login);
```

My TokenResponse:

```
    public class TokenResponse {

    private String access_token;
    private String token_type;
    private Integer expires_in;

    @SerializedName(".issued")
    @Expose
    private String issued;

    @SerializedName(".expires")
    @Expose
    private String expires;



    public String getAccess_token() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getToken_type() {
        return token_type;
    }

    public void setToken_type(String token_type) {
        this.token_type = token_type;
    }

    public Integer getExpires_in() {
        return expires_in;
    }

    public void setExpires_in(Integer expires_in) {
        this.expires_in = expires_in;
    }

    public String getExpires() {
        return expires;
    }

    public void setExpires(String expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
    }

    public String getIssued() {
        return issued;
    }

    public void setIssued(String issued) {
        this.issued = issued;
    }
}
```

My Login class:

```
public class Login {

        @SerializedName("UserName")
        @Expose
        private String UserName;
        @SerializedName("Password")
        @Expose
        private String Password;
        @SerializedName("grant_type")
        @Expose
        private String grant_type;
        @SerializedName("Culture")
        @Expose
        private String Culture;

        public String getUserName() {
            return UserName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            UserName = userName;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return Password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            Password = password;
        }

        public String getGrant_type() {
            return grant_type;
        }

        public void setGrant_type(String grant_type) {
            this.grant_type = grant_type;
        }

        public String getCulture() {
            return Culture;
        }

        public void setCulture(String culture) {
            Culture = culture;
        }
    }
```

In my activity I used it like below:

```
Login login = new Login();

        login.setUserName("username");
        login.setPassword("ab154211254");
        login.setGrant_type("password");
        login.setCulture("ar");

       apiInstence.loginUser(login).enqueue(new Callback<TokenResponse>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<TokenResponse> call, @NonNull Response<TokenResponse> response) {

               int req = response.code();

               Log.d("req",req+"");

               Log.d("onResponse", "onResponse: "+response.body());



           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<TokenResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

           }
       });
```

I have set internet permission in the manifest also but nothing work. Anyone please help me with this ...

Comment: show the loginUser method too.

Comment: i showed in bottom of my first code take look

Comment: @VivekMishra i edit my question

Comment: What does it return??

Comment: error code 400 every time

Comment: @jack What are you appending as header in you request in postman ?

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded @quicklearner

Comment: posted answer, Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try like this.**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("token")
Call<TokenResponse> loginUser(@Field("UserName") String UserName,
                              @Field("Password") String Password, 
                              @Field("grant_type") String grant_type, 
                              @Field("Culture") String Culture);
```

Comment: but i couldn't vote for you  sorry they say
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Answer (score 0):

> Please correct your login method in api interface class with this line

```
@FormUrlEncoded
```

then the method looks like this.

```
 @POST("token")
 @FormUrlEncoded
 Call<TokenResponse> loginUser(@Body Login login);
```

Comment: i got error 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)